# Attributed label with custom line height cropping text on top

Tags: ios, fonts, interface-builder, uilabel, nsattributedstring

[image: Cropped text]

I need to decrease line spacing on interface builder using attributed text, and changing the line height multiplier it works as desired, but the text is being cropped on top.
I already tried to set the `lineSpacing` with `NSMutableParagraphStyle` by code but did not worked or happened the same thing.

There is a way to fix the alignment or setting the correctly the line spacing?

[image: Line height on interface builder]

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't a matter of spacing, but more likely constraints. Perhaps your baseline setting is set to none, in which case try changing it to 'Align Centers'.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm already using `Align Centers` on Baseline property